# how to send special characters data as it is: MAU`A` in XQUERY or in OSB

Tags: osb

I am invoking CRM REST API where I have to send data with special characters. currently, it is eliminating special chars and sending to target `service.My` processing instructor is `UTF-8.`

```
"customFields" : 
 {
  "CO":{
      "brk_cnpj" : "50.132.588/0001-05",
      "brk_inmobiliaria" : false,
      "brk_rua" : "MAUA"
       }
```

I want to send data in same format: `"brk_rua" : "MAUA"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to send the character ' for example. Have you tried encoding it?

https://www.werockyourweb.com/url-escape-characters/